# Bokeh auto-scaling axes, after adding secondary y-axis

Tags: python, python-3.x, plot, bokeh

I am trying to plot two sets of graphs on one figure with a secondary y-axis. I can't get both of them to do auto-scaling according to the data.

I can't set the ranges because I am tabbing 10 figures and the code will be used for different sources whose ranges will vary. Also, currently, I have one range set to specific values but I would like to have them both set to auto-scaling.

The dataframe looks like:

Wavelength         340    440    550    ...    340std    440std
2017-07-01 14:40   2.05   3.02   2.14   ...    0.002     0.00054
....

```
TOOLS = "pan,wheel_zoom,box_zoom,reset,save"
p = figure(tools=TOOLS, x_axis_type='datetime',plot_height=400, 
           plot_width=700,
           outline_line_color = 'gray',
           y_axis_label = 'Radiance[W/m^2.sr.nm]',
           y_range = DataRange1d()
          )
# Setting the second y axis range name and range
p.extra_y_ranges = {"foo": Range1d(start=0, end=0.000006)}

# Adding the second axis to the plot.  
p.add_layout(LinearAxis(y_range_name="foo"), 'right')

p.line(x='Time', y='340.0', line_color="darkcyan", line_width=1, 
       source=source)
p.line(x='Time',y='340.0std', line_color = 'red', line_width=1, 
       y_range_name="foo", source=source)

one = Panel(child=row(p), title='wavelength_one')
tabs = Tabs(tabs = [one,two,three,four,five,six])

show(tabs)
```

The current output looks as follows:
[image: Output Screenshot]

Answer (score 5):

A few things should be noted:

- If you supply explicit range values, either by using a fixed `Range1d` or by manually setting `start` or `end` on a `DataRange1d` then Bokeh assumes you are doing that on purpose, and won't override your settings (i.e. no data-ranging anymore)
- Just FYI, since it is not clear what you are after, Bokeh "twin" axes will *always* maintain their original relative scale to one another. The cannot vary independently once initialized. (e.g. zooming one will zoom the other by the same proportion)
- `DataRange1d` objects have a `renderers` property that you can specify, to explicitly tell the range which glyphs to consider when auto-ranging. By default `DataRange1d` automatically try to consider every available glyph, unless you tell it otherwise:

  ```
  r1 = p.line(...)

  p.y_range.renderers = [r1] # only auto-range based on this one line
  ```
- I'm not sure it will work to have two auto-ranges with twin axes. AFAIK no one has ever tried. You may only be able to set auto-ranging by configuring the main range `DataRange1d` with one of the glyphs, and an initial fixed range `Range1d` on the extra (that will scale as the other main range scales)

Answer (score 0):

I am working also with data streaming with bokeh. I had the same problem, and I have been searching for a solution. I have just tried a new thing, which helped me to solve this problem.
Try this: Instead of putting `y_range = DataRange1d()`, just set None value to `y_range = None`. For every callback it should be same I think. I hope this helps you to solve this problem.